# LINQ .ToDictionary for 2d dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have 3 dictionary below:

```
Dictionary<string, int> A = new Dictionary<string, int>();
Dictionary<string, int> B = new Dictionary<string, int>();
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>> C = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>();
```

I want to fill C Dictionary with default value = 0 like below and my code is incorrect please help me

```
C = A.ToDictionary(x => x.Value, B.ToDictionary(y => y.Value, y => 0));
```

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
C = A.ToDictionary(x => x.Value, v=>B.ToDictionary(y => y.Value, y => 0));
```